# Is there a downside to using get() in dplyr instead of SE?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have been reading about SE and NSE in dplyr, and have run into a problem where I actually need SE. I have the following function that is supposed to find rows where some items match, but the target variable doesn't:

```
find_dataset_inconsistencies <- function(df, target_column, cols_to_use) {
  inconsists <- df %>% 
    group_by_at(cols_to_use) %>% 
    summarise(uTargets = length(unique(get(target_column)))) %>% 
    filter(uTargets > 1)
}
```

This seems to work in my case. However, the **get(target_column)** is a workaround because I need SE of my variable and cannot hardcode the column name. I initially tried to do it with the SE version (`summarise_(.dots = ...)`), but had trouble finding the correct syntax for evaluating target_column.

My question is the following: Is there any downside to simply using `get()`? Are the any cases where this will not work? Any risks / slowdowns? Simply using `get` is definitely way more readable than the "correct" SE syntax.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done with NSE, with `rlang`.

Assuming your use case is:

```
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "mpg", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
# # A tibble: 8 x 6
# # Groups:   cyl, vs, am, gear [5]
#     cyl    vs    am  gear  carb uTargets
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <int>
# 1  4.00  1.00  0     4.00  2.00        2
# 2  4.00  1.00  1.00  4.00  1.00        4
# 3  4.00  1.00  1.00  4.00  2.00        2
# 4  6.00  1.00  0     3.00  1.00        2
# 5  6.00  1.00  0     4.00  4.00        2
# 6  8.00  0     0     3.00  2.00        4
# 7  8.00  0     0     3.00  3.00        3
# 8  8.00  0     0     3.00  4.00        4
```

You could:

```
library(dplyr)

f2 <- function(df, target_column, cols_to_use) {
  group_by_at(df, cols_to_use) %>% 
    summarise(uTargets = n_distinct(!! rlang::sym(target_column))) %>% 
    filter(uTargets > 1)
}

all.equal(
  find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "mpg", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")),
  f2(mtcars, "mpg", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
)
# [1] TRUE
```

---

Actual answer to your question about risks:

Now imagine you have `foo <- 3` in your global environment. Compare:

```
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "foo", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
# A tibble: 0 x 6
# Groups:   cyl, vs, am, gear [0]
# ... with 6 variables: cyl <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>, gear <dbl>,
#   carb <dbl>, uTargets <int>
```

which will silently return an empty data frame, and:

```
f2(mtcars, "foo", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
# Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : variable 'foo' not found
```

which will raise an error that directly points you to the bug.

---

**Edit**

Since you seem to be after the "tidyverse way", I'd recommend the following. The underlying philosophy seems to be to discourage as much as possible the use of variables names as strings, and rather as bare names:

```
f3 <- function(df, target_column, ...) {
  target_column <- enquo(target_column)
  cols_to_use <- quos(...)
  group_by(df, !!! cols_to_use) %>% 
    summarise(uTargets = n_distinct(!! target_column)) %>% 
    filter(uTargets > 1)
}
all.equal(
  find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "mpg", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb")),
  f3(mtcars, target_column = mpg, cyl, vs, am, gear, carb)
)
# [1] TRUE
```

`f3()`'s interface is also designed to resemble that of other tidyverse functions, and potentially better integrate in a tidyverse pipeline of transformations.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. The problem with get seems to be that get() expands scope by default - rlang::sym() does not? Or is there another difference that I missed? I still have some trouble with R's scoping rules since I have a C++ background...

Comment: `get(target_column, df)` ignores grouping of the data frame.

Comment: @Thomas: Actually, I don't know. I have trouble with that too. I was surprised to find that it is the specific combination of `n_distinct` and `sym` that works this way. `length(unique())` with `sym` behaves like `get()`. I should have made it clearer... that it's not completely clear...

Comment: I tried that too, it seems it still ignores grouping. Also, my misunderstanding of what n_distinct does in mutate or summarize is deeper than I thought. I have to investigate. There seems to be a couple of issues pending wrt n_distinct

Comment: I have transferred my comments to an answer and it required some experimentation but I believe it is working now with `get`.

Comment: @Thomas : See my new edit for a more "tidyverse-friendly" way

Answer (score 2):

@Aurele has already shown how to do it using rlang but I thought it would be interesting to see if we can get it working using `get` as well.  As pointed out my first few attempts at `get` did not work but after some experimentation this seems to work as desired.  This is not to say I am suggesting this but just for interest sake here it is.

### 1. get/do

If we wrap the summarize statement in `do` then we can use `get(..., .)` like this and it will work as desired.  This is probably the easiest and most straight forward way to use `get` within `group by`.  The key observation is that within `do` the dot refers to those only rows within the current  group whereas outside of `do` it refers to all rows of the input when used in the actual argument to a nested function call.

```
find_dataset_inconsistencies <- function(df, target_column, cols_to_use) {
  df %>% 
    group_by_at(cols_to_use) %>% 
    do(summarise(., uTargets = length(unique(get(target_column, .))))) %>% 
    filter(uTargets > 1)
}

# gives desired result
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "mpg", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
# ... snip correct output ...

# correctly gives an error indicating it can't find `foo`
foo <- 3
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "foo", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
```

### 2. get reaching into grandparent with inherits=FALSE

```
find_dataset_inconsistencies <- function(df, target_column, cols_to_use) {
  df %>% 
    group_by_at(cols_to_use) %>% 
    summarise(uTargets = length(unique(get(target_column,
       parent.env(parent.env(environment())), inherits = FALSE)))) %>% 
    filter(uTargets > 1)
}

# gives desired result
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "mpg", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
# ... snip correct output ...

# correctly gives an error indicating it can't find `foo`
foo <- 3
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "foo", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
## Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
##   Evaluation error: object 'foo' not found.
```

To make this solution a bit more streamlined we could define `GET` like this:

```
GET <- function(x) {
  p <- parent.frame()
  p3 <- parent.env(parent.env(p))
  get(x, p3, inherits = FALSE)
}

find_dataset_inconsistencies <- function(df, target_column, cols_to_use) {
  df %>% 
    group_by_at(cols_to_use) %>% 
    summarise(uTargets = length(unique(GET(target_column)))) %>% 
    filter(uTargets > 1)
}

# gives expected answer    
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "mpg", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))

# gives expected error
foo <- 3
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "foo", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
```

### 3. subset by key column

Another possibility would be to subset by a key column.  `mtcars` has no such column but if we make the row names into such a column then we would have one:

```
library(tidyr)
find_dataset_inconsistencies <- function(df, target_column, cols_to_use) {
  df %>% 
    rownames_to_column %>%
    group_by_at(cols_to_use) %>% 
    summarise(uTargets = length(unique(
        get(target_column, .[.$rowname %in% rowname, ])))) %>% 
    filter(uTargets > 1)
}

# gives expected answer
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "mpg", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))

# gives expected error
find_dataset_inconsistencies(mtcars, "foo", c("cyl", "vs", "am", "gear", "carb"))
```

Comment: These are valid suggestions and seem to work on my actual dataset as well. Thanks! I hope you don't mind me marking Aureles answer as solution since that seems the "tidyverse" way of doing it.

Comment: I did specifically write that I was *not* suggesting this.

Comment: Was in no way meant as a criticism :-)